# How to Upload Photo to Facebook with Mango phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

recently been interested in using windows phone to upload photo. I have upgraded my windows phone to mango version. would appreciate if you can help me with what api I need and how to upload a photo to facebook. Link of references or sample app links to learn will be greatlly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/csharpsdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/72008) on codeplex to do this.

There is both sample code and tutorial links on the site.

You'll first have to use the authentication APIs to log the user in and then the upload APIs to send the image to Facebook.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Wow.. alot of documenation to read. Before going any further, I like to know if I make a Windows Phone App with this API from FaceBook C# SDK and sell on AppStore, is this OK? Any issue of selling? any license issue? Thanks

Comment: @MilkBottle It's under MPL so that means you have the permission to sell any products you build with the SDK and you don't have to pay any royalties. Read 'patent grant' under the license [link](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/license). If this helps, please mark my answer as Answered! Thanks!

Comment: Pardon me. I downloaded as per your link for the aug version. downloaded both. I am pretty new to facebook. Just setup facebook acct. Where is the Facebook api or DLL ? No folder with with name refer as api or DLL. Appreciate if you can help. Thanks

Comment: @MilkBottle I haven't used the SDK myself so i can't give you hands on help but in the documentation, they have a step by step tutorial to get started [here](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx). And lots of sample code and documentation [here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation). Sorry i cant be of more help!